# Sublime Text 3: Preferences menu greyed

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 on my Mac (10.13.2)

The Preferences menu is always greyed and not usable. (even on restart)
Any idea to solve that?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Having the same issue, and it looks like it's an issue that's been in sublime for several years according to https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/preferences-greyed-out-in-os-x/2706/23 . So far the workaround has been to just quit and re-open Sublime Text. Have you tried disabling some plugins?

Answer (score 6):

On macOS, I deleted the file **Package Control.last-run** in **/Users/cookedapple/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User** and restarted Sublime Text 3. The problem was resolved.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I deleted `rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User/Package\ Control.last-run` and restarted Sublime Text 3, but Preferences is still greyed out.

Comment: Worked for me. After re-launching Sublime Text 3 it took about a minute for some of the nested settings to become not grayed out as well.

Answer (score 1):

[There](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/preferences-greyed-out-in-os-x/2706) have been some suggestions that third-party Mac apps may be causing issues. So you may try restarting Sublime Text – I guess you have already done that before looking for a solution, try to do that again after each of the following steps:

- Restarting menu bar Bartender or SecondBar if present
- Reinstalling latest installed ST packages
- Delete(https://stackoverflow.com/a/48398420/880188) `Package Control.last-run`, i.e. via Terminal: `rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User/Package\ Control.last-run` as mentioned in the [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48398420/880188)
- Restarting the computer

Answer (score 1):

A user has figured out a reliable way to reproduce this (see [Kronuz' comment from 6/19/18 on the issue tracker](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/2196#issuecomment-398413897)).

It seems to be caused by packages containing a large amount of files. There might be other causes as well, but hopefully with at least one reliable way to repro, the devs will come up with a fix.